# Have added Ivy management to Eclipse project, then what?

Tags: eclipse, ivy

Have added Ivy management to one of my eclipse projects. Nothing happened after that.

I have a guide to add something to `ivy.xml` and `ivysettings.xml`, so what? How to create empty versions of these files? Where to put them?

I have created some by intuition, in the project root, then added to files what was told.

Nothing happened. Where are new libraries? How to force Ivy to do something?

Versions:
  Apache IvyDE  2.2.0.beta1-201203282058-RELEASE
  Eclipse Helios Service Release 2

Guides for ivy are for xuggler: http://www.xuggle.com/downloads

I have created `ivy.xml` by `File New` and added what was said without ellipsis. `icysettings.xml` are just the sample w/o ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Yes ivy.xml should be in the root (for default configuration).
try this:

```
<ivy-module 
    version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd"
    xmlns:e="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/extra"> 

       <info organisation="com.organisation" module="stackoverflow" revision="1.0.0" status="integration" >
       </info>

       <configurations>
           <conf name="default" />
       </configurations>

       <dependencies>
                    <dependency org="xuggle" name="xuggle-xuggler" rev="5.2" />
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Create ivysettings.xml file in the root as well. This one is adapted to your need

```
<ivysettings> <
    settings defaultResolver="default" />
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml" />

    <resolvers>
        <url m2compatible="true" name="xugglecode">
            <ivy
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organization]/[artifact]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            <ivy
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organization]/[artifact]/ivy-[revision].xml" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organisation]/[artifact]/[revision]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organisation]/[artifact]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[organisation]/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/[artifact](-[revision]).[ext]" />
            <artifact
                pattern="http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/red5_jdk6_stable/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/workingcopy/dist/[artifact].[ext]" />
        </url>
        <chain name="default" changingPattern=".*SNAPSHOT">
            <resolver ref="xugglecode" />
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

Now when you add ivy management, in Main tab you should see Ivy File: ivy.xml as default.
now go to settings tab. Check the box of 'Enable project specific settings'.
in Ivy settings path, easier to choose the one you just created in your root project using 'Workspace button'. Navigate and choose.

Press ok. It will start resolving immediately.
I should tell you, that even though the file exists, I couldn't retrieve it. The ivy- console seems stuck. I'm receiving Status Code 403. I'm doing from work.

Maybe you have better luck resolving it. If not, consider this as a mini example of how to set up IvyDE.